# How to reuse router object on another html page in Backbone JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am fairly new to Backbone JS and still figuring out its nuances.

I have created a router class in main.js which is included in index.html. Also, I have created an object of that router class associated to same html page.

Now, if I redirect to next html page all the created objects get lost. Even if I associate it to window object, it also get lost on a page redirect.

So, my question is how do I reuse my router object on next html page without storing it in **sessionStorage** or **localStorage**?

Should I always include the router js file on each html page and create a new object every time? Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do? Please enlighten me.

Comment: I think BackboneJS, AngularJS and those js frameworks were thought for Single Web Application so if you want to use the same js logic in other html file you would need the same js files linked. You could consider use some template js framework like handlebars

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain a bit in detail about handlebars. Underscore is already included in Backbone, so I can use that. How do you suggest to handle my requirement using them?

Comment: I don't know your architecture of course but when I meant maybe use some template system is because you could avoid redirect to another page and just play with many templates for your differents views. Suppose you have an app with 3 sections, 3 routes entrypoints: #/main, #/dashboard, #/config and 3 templates or views. Each route fires request for data to server which you bind for the corresponding template and show it. Something like that, it is SPA (Single Page Application, just one index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js is primarily designed to create SPAs (single Page Applications) especially the routing which is based on the hash change events by default.

For some reason if you must have actual redirection between HTML pages, then considered each as separate applications, i.e both should load the libraries, setup their own backbone components etc. Data can be shared between them using client side solutions like `localStorage` or REST API.